# Is it possible to batch process SAS programs from a local machine to a remote server using SAS EG?

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a simple UI in SAS EG where users can add their local sas files and batch submit them to a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have local SAS datasets, you probably have a local installation of Base SAS - in which case you can upload the data via SAS/Connect (if installed).  Make sure your selected server is 'local' in the EG program editor and run the following (modify as per your site details):

```
/* prepare credentials */
%let remote  = your.server 7551;
%let sasuser = &sysuserid;
%let saspass={sas002}BA7B9D061CA7F9601F317DCA06C4CFCC;
options comamid=tcp remote=remote;

/* signon and assign remote library */
signon sasuat nocscript user=&sasuser password="&saspass";
rsubmit;
libname example (work);
endrsubmit;
libname example (example) server=remote;

/* add a local SAS dataset to the remote library */
data example.ex1;
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan. You are correct. However, we are slowly migrating to SAS EG and will be not renewing our Base SAS license. Therefore, we will not be relying on Base SAS in the future.

Comment: Another option might be to create your datasets using cards files (ie, run the .sas programs in EG to create the target datasets directly on the server).  This is only really feasiable if volumes are small!  See macro here: https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/base/mp_ds2cards.sas.  This is documented here:  https://rawsas.github.io/coredoc/files.html